# Set two types of section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have changed the format of the section numbering so each section name starts with *Práctica 1: title*, instead of *1. Title*. The problem is that I want to reset the format to the original in the last part of my document (in the appendix) so it does not start as *Práctica A: text*.

Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
 \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad   
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Práctica \thesection: }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}

\begin{document}
\section{Medida del crecimiento y/o respiración celular}
%This section title is displayed as "Práctica 1: Medida del crecimiento y/o respiración celular"
\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\section{Códigos para Berkeley Madonna}
%This section title is displayed as "Práctica A:..." too.
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\let\orig@seccntformat\@seccntformat` before redefining it and then `\let\@seccntformat\orig@seccntformat` after `\begin{appendices}. The `\let` primitive copies the definition of some macro to another macro name which can be restored later on, or just redefine `\prefix@section` again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way... change `\prefix@section` at the begin of `appendices` again to use `\prefix@@section` which is defined to expand to nothing.

The `\g@addto@macro` usage for `\appendices` adds the `\restoreprefixsection` macro to be automatically executed at `\begin{appendices}`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
 \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad   
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section

\newcommand{\prefix@@section}{Práctica }
\newcommand\prefix@section{\prefix@@section \thesection: }

\newcommand{\restoreprefixsection}{%
  \renewcommand{\prefix@@section}{}%
}

\g@addto@macro{\appendices}{\restoreprefixsection}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}

\begin{document}
\section{Medida del crecimiento y/o respiración celular}
%This section title is displayed as "Práctica 1: Medida del crecimiento y/o respiración celular"
\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\section{Códigos para Berkeley Madonna}
%This section title is displayed as "Práctica A:..." too.
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```